# Android - Why Activity is Open after click notification?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, notifications

I have a function to display a notification, which I call from various activities.

```
public static void CrearNotificacion(Context pContexto, String pTituloBarra, String pTitulo, String pTexto){
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) pContexto.getSystemService(ns);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icono, pTituloBarra, System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(pContexto, pContexto.getClass());
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(pContexto, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(pContexto, pTitulo, pTexto, contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

works perfect, the problem is that pressing on the notification opens the activity that created the notification and that's wrong, I think the notiifcacion activity should not open when I select the notification.

Why? there any way to fix this?

I do not want to open any activity when I select the notification.

thanks from now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to have no action taken when clicking the notification, you may set an empty Intent as follows:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent() ;
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(pContexto, pContexto.getClass());
```

i guess this is the line you have to change with

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(pContexto, yourClass.class);
```